# Blender exported DXF not to scale in other program

Tags: export, scale

When I export my object from Blender to import to a different program, the scale is completely different. I know it's not the other program because when I try to import in another program, it shows up the same scale.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try would be to set the units in the 'other' application to metres before importing. This is what works in Rhino, for example.